# Understanding list of objects based View syntax ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I created View using Visual Studio Template which should display list of objects. Here is the syntax Visual Studio generated:

```
@model IEnumerable<TestMVCApplication.Models.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.available)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.price)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.available)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I am confused about above syntax. Particularly:

1) First time we see this above:

```
   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
```

I know to refer to model we should use `Model` (**with capital M**).
Why is above it used with small `m`? What does `model` (with small m)
mean above? How does IDE know that `model.name` exists (with small m).

**If `Model.Name` would be used it would mean that `IEnumerable` has property `Name` (right?) but that is not the case right? Explanation for dummies appreciated.** So what is really `model` (with small m)?

2) Finally this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
```

is also confusing. what is `modelItem` - it was not declared anywhere? How come it appeared here? How this works? would not it be more logical to have `item=> item.name` ?

Comment: The model and modelItem used here are just the parameter name to your lambda functions. You can even name it anyway you want like m or mitem. Just look for some information on Lambda  expressions in google.

Comment: @Thangadurai: If I can write anything, how does it know here: `model => model.available` that `model.available` - property exists?? Your explanation is really scarce too, I did basic research before asking.

Comment: Post your model object Product here. For your information the extension method DisplayNameFor is actually expecting a IEnumerable. You really need to google a bit about Data Annotations, method extensions and check the syntax of those HTML helper classes in MSDN.

Comment: @Thangadurai: So you have googled this and can't explain the answer to me? I told you I already did search before asking. PS. This is the model: `public class Product
    {
        public string name {get;set;}
        public int ID {get; set;}
        public bool available {get;set;}
        public int price {get; set;}
    }`

Comment: @Thangadurai: So it expects IEnumerable? then is `model` IENumerable? Like I said I thought you should always use `Model` with campital M. Further even if model is `IEnumerable`, how come `model.Name` makes sense?

Comment: There are two things. 1. You are keep getting confused with 'Model' and 'model' used in the lambda expression. If you just take a look at those extension methods, they pass the Model object to your lambda expression (lambda expressions are somewhat similar to normal functions with parameters), in this case, the parameter is named as 'model'. 2. The DisplayNameFor looks for metadata and returns the name of the Display name attribute (if used) otherwise just the Name of the property itself (i.e. model.Name will not return the value of Name instead either the Display name attr. name or 'Name')

Comment: @Thangadurai: So if I had written instead `doesntexist => doesntexist .JonDoe` - then the table header would be "JonDoe"??

Answer (score 0):

I don't have hands on MVC but I can clarify your 2nd question.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)
```

Well this has got nothing to do with MVC, if you (really) know lambda expression and anonymous functions. Here modelItem is parameter and item.price is a return value. Imagine translating this to:

```
TypeOfPriceProp AnonymousFunction(SomeType modelItem) {
   return item.price;
}
```

Now this function would not work if you called it directly because it does not know about **item**. However, lambda expressions make it possible because they can refer to the variables from outer scope as well. Outer scope here is `@foreach (var item in Model)` which defines **item**.

In short, you can say in `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)` modelItem parameter is not used at all (also it does not need to be declared. Thanks to lambda). In fact, if you changed that item.price to modelItem.price, it would not work.

Comment: ok I think I understand explanation for 2nd question  - thanks. But first question still remains unclear!

Comment: Yes your 1st question is really interesting. And things have got confusing because of that IEnumerable. :)

Comment: Yes but as you can see no one has answered so far ?! I don't know how to increase attention to this question

Comment: You asked this 19 hours ago and has around 50 views. Although this is low, just give it some more time. I have also started learning MVC and your 1st question will help me as well. Meanwhile why don't you debug (I am sure razor can be debugged) and check what comes into "model" at run-time. I mean it's type, value etc.

Comment: I can't see that value in debugger

Answer (score -1):

If you would look at the definitions of these two methods on msdn, you will find that they are extension methods for HTMLHelper class. So, these methods are aware of the "Model". This helper method expects a lambda expression as parameter.

Which is the following 
`Expression<TDelegate>` class and it represents a delegate. In this particular Case the delegate is

`Func<TModel, TValue>`

the TModel is an input parameter which is of type "Model" in this case.

Now the "model" is nothing but an instance of "Model", you can name it to anything and it will work in same fashion.

You need to do some further reading on anonymous functions to understand it fully.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: if `model` is instance of `Model` - then `Model` is of type `IEnumerable` right? How come `IEnumerable` has properties like `available`??? PS. Also are you sure if I use inside html `model` I will not get syntax error? (with small m) ?!

Comment: @user30044, people are trying their level best to provide better answers. Your 'tone' doesn't sound good for a forum like this. I don't see anything wrong in this answer

Comment: @Thangadurai: because I have put time and effort in formulating a question, and so should the ones who provide an answer

Comment: I agree with @Thangadurai. OP, asking the question was your need so you must take efforts to do initial rnd, formatting etc, everyone has to. Answering the question is a help that you asked for. So please be considerate and polite. This is in fact mentioned in SO guidelines as well.

Comment: @vnikhil: This is answer is simply wrong, so there is nothing more I can add here. Anyway, enough with comments on this answer, I think it is not worth anymore.